# The destruction of objects in the java game

Tags: java, object, memory, destruction

I have the object bonus in my java game. When the object hero touches the object bonus, the object bonus must be destroyed, disappear from the screen and not take up the memory.
How to do it?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: turning off the computer would do that.

Comment: Show us what you tried, damn.

Comment: If only there was some way to let the JVM know that an object was ready to be garbage collected....

Comment: Actually, @assylias, you gave me a great idea: you can destroy any object if you have a hammer...

Comment: Good luck guaranteeing that last part instantly when you're running in a language with a GC :)

Comment: @JackManey That would also remove it from the screen.

Comment: Trolling aside, `finalize` that object. But that's not a conformation that the object would be cleared, just telling the GC that it is ready to be cleared

Comment: @noMAD: Never, ever, ever, *ever* call `finalize` yourself.  It's only for the runtime to call, on an object it's already destroying, before it reclaims the object's memory.  If `finalize` does anything other than prepare an already-unreachable object for destruction or resuscitate it, it's doing something wrong.

Comment: @noMAD: I take it back; there is exactly one occasion when you'd call `finalize` -- if you're *writing* a finalizer, you'd call `super.finalize()` at the end so the base class can do  whatever finalization it has to.  Other than that, though, never ever call it.  Not even on subobjects of the object your finalizer's running on -- the runtime will handle that.

Answer (score 4):

Simply remove them from the collection of availabe bonus objects.

The java VM will later detect that there is no more reference to the bonus object, and will free up the memory.

If you have hundred thousands of such objects, it will help to set them to explicitly to `null`, to free up memory a bit faster.

Comment: Setting them to `null` won't help, but this is correct otherwise.